# Show $\exists a >0$ such that $f(x) \ge a$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and suppose $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Show that there exists a number $a>0$ such that $f(x) \ge a$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

I have a feeling that we will need to show that $a = \inf\{f(x): x\in [0,1]\}$ and then that $a>0$. Is this correct (and enough)? Also, how will go about showing this?

Note that I know the following:

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, which is a compact set, hence we know that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and attains its supremum and infimum on $[0,1]$.

Comment: The set $\{f(x): x\in [0,1]\}$ contains its minimum. Do you have that result? (Sometimes known as the Extreme Value Theorem.)

Comment: @SimonS - I edited it in just now :) . See updated on what I know :)

Comment: Ok. So since $f$ attains its minimum there is some $b \in [0,1]$ such that $f(b) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. As $f$ is positive on that interval, $f(b) > 0$. Hence ...

Comment: @SimonS - Thank you! :). Please provide this as an answer so that I can give credit where credit is due :) :)

Comment: It's ok. Next time I write a good answer you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on a compact domain ,hence obtains a minimum (By the extreme value theorem) . $f(y)=a$ is the minimum for some $y\in[0,1]$. Since $f(x)>0$ for all x, $a>0$. Since it's a minimum $f(x)\geq a$ for all x.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{f(x) \colon x \in [0,1]\}$. Since for all $s\in S$, $s >0$, we know that $\inf (S)\geq 0$ (why?). Now we just need to show that $\inf (S)>0$.

If $\inf (S)=0$, then by the extreme value theorem $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, contradicting that $f(x)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it this way: taking advantage of the fact that $f$ is strictly positive continuous function, we have $g=1/f$ is also a positive continuous function on $[0,1]$. $g$ being continuous on $[0,1]$ attains a maximum, say, $a>0$. That is $g(x)=|g(x)|\leq a$ on $[0,1]$. Equivalently, $f(x)=|f(x)| \geq a$ on $[0,1]$.

Just for fun, with the same kind of argument, I think we can say that if a continuous function defined on a compact set has a minimum, then it can only attains it at the the zeros of the function.